# Get the value of git command in shell script

Tags: bash, git, shell, husky

I want to use husky to run a shell script to return `exit 1` if a user includes the `--tags` option in a git push command.

I have husky set up like this in my package.json

```
"husky": {
  "hooks": {
    "pre-push": "sh stopTagPush.sh"
  }
}
```

When I run the command `git push origin --tags` this runs my script but I don't know how to get access to the value of the git command `git push origin --tags` to see if `--tags` is present. Is there a git variable that I can use to access the command value inside the script?

Comment: You don't have access to the exact command, but the pre-push hook receives information about what would be pushed on its standard input, see [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push).

Comment: Users can include `--no-verify` and the hooks won't run, so it's not  being enforced